# How can I toggle two elements without removing in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html

```
<div>
<span data-disabled class="myclass"> like </span>
<span class="myclass"> unlike </span>
</div>
```

scss is like this

```
myclass{
     visibility: visible;
        cursor: pointer;

        &[data-disabled] {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
}
```

and based on click I am doing this

```
        this.select('like').attr('data-disabled', true);
        this.select('unlike').removeAttr('data-disabled');
```

It is working fine but my like and unlike are shown next to each other and they hide and become visible at their original position.

Is there any way to have same position and when I hide and unhide then they overwrite each other.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for us? Would like to see this in action.

Comment: Use `display` instead of `visibility`.

Comment: All you need is `toggle` function and your good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the visibilty property you are using. You have to use `display:none` so that the item will not consume the space when hidden.

instead of

```
visibility: hidden;
```

use

```
display: none;
```

You can read more about [**it here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone).

Answer (score 0):

Try **JQuery Toggle** function to achieve this task:

```js
 $(function(){
    $(".myclass").click(function () {
        $(".myclass").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span class="myclass"> like </span>
    <span class="myclass" style="display:none"> unlike </span>
    </div>
```